# MS Access Office 365 keeps crashing when opening a popup form

Tags: ms-access

I am using a windows 7 Enterprise 32-bit operating system and Microsoft Access 365 ProPlus.

I open a form then when I double click on a field it triggers an event procedure that opens another form.  This form is a Pop Up form (non model) single form default view.  Everything was working great for the last year or so and for some reason when I open the form this way the access program crashes.

I can open the form by selecting it from the search forms dialog.
What I found works is I need to open the form then edit it in design view.  Make a small change in the form and save it.  Then view it in form view and close the form.  Once I have done all this I can run my program normally and everything works great until I close access and re-open it.  Then I need to do it all over again.

I have ran the compact and repair tool several times.

My code is a very simple one:

```
On Error GoTo Err_Command18_Click

Dim intBuildingId As Integer
Dim StDocName As String

intBuildingId = Form_Frm_Buildings.Building_ID
StDocName = "Frm_Buildings_To_Frm_Manager"

Me.Refresh
DoCmd.OpenForm StDocName
Forms(StDocName).Recordset.FindFirst "Building_Id = " & intBuildingId

Err_Command18_Click:
Exit Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance!

Mark

Comment: Have you decompiled? Have you repaired the installation? Where does building id come from? As an aside, you should always give controls relevant names.

Comment: Have you really got a form called  **Form_Frm_Buildings.Building_ID** ?  - The Form_ construct is used by access to refer to modules. The correct syntax to use would be Forms!FrmBuildings!Building_ID

Comment: Building id comes from the form Frm_Buildings
I'll try to decompile and let you know.

Comment: I did a decompile then another compact and repair.  Closed access and re-opened it.  It looks to be working.  Thanks for the comments and help!